# PHP Что быстрее uset двух столбцов двумерного массива или пересоздать?

Tags: php

Возник вопрос, что будет быстрее. Удалить два столбца в массиве или создать новый массив. Вот код, который имеется сейчас и который не устраивает. 
В начале идет сложный SQL запрос, который возвращает в т.ч. лишние данные. Повторяющиеся в каждой строке. Но это быстрее чем делать два дополнительных запроса. Его я опускаю, написав в комментариях "рыбу".

```
// $list = QueryTableFromSQL( "SELECT TABLE_NAME, TOTAL, FILTERED FROM bla bla bla " )
$total = $list[0]["TOTAL"];
$filtered = $list[0]["FILTERED"];
$glue = "";
$query = "";
foreach( $list as $i => $rec )
{
    $tname = $rec['TABLE_NAME'];
    if (CheckProtectedTables($tname)) // used local data
    {
        $list[$i]['protected'] = 'protected';
    } 
    unset( $list[$i]["TOTAL"]);
    unset( $list[$i]["FILTERED"]);
}
```

вопрос в чем вот эти два unset() в цикле, не будет ли быстрее просто создать новый массив и перепихать туда одно поле, изредка добавляя второе, чем для каждой строки массива вызывать два unset?

Comment: у вас там тысячи строк в массиве чтобы разницу заметить? `array_column` + цикл, либо `array_map` вам в помощь.

Comment: А зачем два ансета вызывать - у него же произвольное число параметров :-D правда, не думаю, что это на что-то повлияет. Не совсем понимаю один момент - "в начале идет сложный sql запрос, который возвращает в т.ч. лишние данные" - чему противоречит убрать лишние данные из запроса? oO? или они еще где-то используются потом?

Comment: unset освобождает память, создание массива наоборот нагружает ее, но влияние вы почувствуете только при сотнях тысяч/миллионах элементов, что нереально для 99,99% проектов

Comment: > чему противоречит убрать лишние данные из запроса?     Ну, скорее всего, недостаточное знание SQL. Запрос возвращает: некое количество строк из таблицы согласно переданному условию where, при этом возвращает только часть этих строк с номерами "с".."по". Но кроме того он же возвращает сколько всего записей в таблице и сколько всего записей соответствует условию. Используется в ответе на ajax запрос от jquery dbtables.(табличка с пагинатором) и как получить все эти данные одним а не тремя запросами (тремя дольше - я проверял). не выдавая "лишних" данных. Я не знаю. квалификация не позволяет.

Comment: > или они еще где-то используются потом?   Да, используются. В коде приведенном в вопросе это видно. Сначала мы их берем из нулевой строки результат и сохраняем: $total = $list[0]["TOTAL"];$filtered = $list[0]["FILTERED"];   А потом стираем из таблицы этими самыми unset'ами. Потому как в той таблице, что выводится таких столбцов нет. Эти два значения нужны для пагинатора.